# Update global variable inside parallel R thread

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Is there a way to have multiple threads update a global variable from each parallel instance?

e.g. a cluster with 15 cores writes to a variable outside of their scope so that intermediary results from each call are collected in aggregate.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ipc/vignettes/shinymp.html

Comment: Can you me more precise? Can you provide code that tries to do this? Which type of variable, a numeric vector?

Answer (score 0):

I have a remedy that works for my issue.

If you simply write to a global variable for each thread, you can `clusterCall` at the end once the run has been finished and aggregate the individual data sets.  I wasn't able to find a solution where each thread has the ability to write to the master thread's global environment.